# Reading array elements without value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this valid json:

```
{"config":{"autoUpdate":3500,"categories":["ristoranti","taxi","hotel"]}}
```

I'd like to read the categories elements, im trying this:

```
var myData:Object = JSON.decode(myLoader.data);
    for (var categories:Object in myData.config.categories ) {
        trace(categories);
        }
```

But this is printing just:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *for - in* loop iterates the **keys** of a key/value object (indices in the case of an Array.) If you want to iterate through the **values** instead, you should use a *for **each** - in* loop.

```
for each (var category:String in myData.config.categories ) {
    trace(category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for **each**:

```
for each (var categories:Object in myData.config.categories )
{
    ...etc
```